# Aurelia Multiple Properties in custom element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm wondering whether I have got the wrong end of the stick here.

I have successfully made a custom component: `event-block.[html|js]`.

In my `event-block.js` file I have:

```
import {inject, bindable} from "aurelia-framework";
import {EventService} from "event.service";

@inject(EventService)
export class EventBlock {
    @bindable day = null;
    @bindable month = null;

    constructor(eventService) {
        console.log(day);
        console.log(month);
    }

    attached() {
        console.log(day);
        console.log(month);
    }
}
```

In my `event-block.html` I have this:

```
<template>
    <div class="cellcontent">
        <span>${day}</span> <span>${month}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

I use it in my other view like so:

```
<td repeat.for="day of days"> <event-block day.bind="day.date()" month.bind="day.month()"></event-block> </td>
```

`day` is a moment object. the rendered output could be:

`1 0`

actual:

`Fri Jan 01 2016 12:45:23 GMT+0000`

When I inspect the DOM, it's showing only one span with that full date in it. So I'm guessing that I'm not using the bindable properties correctly.

How do I use them properly to get the correct output?

Comment: everything looks good to me other than the `console.log` statements in the `EventBlock` class are missing `this.` when accessing the `day` and `month` properties.  eg `console.log(this.day)` instead of `console.log(day)`

Comment: i wasnt seeing any output to the console, not even undefined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It seems you are missing the customElement decorator on your
  EventBlock class.
- There are no locally scoped day/month variables. You need to reference the variables attached to the instance of your class (this.day/this.month)
- Be sure to require the component from your html with a 'require' tag that references the component inside of the 'from' attribute

```js
import {inject, bindable, customElement} from "aurelia-framework";
import {EventService} from "event.service";

@customElement('event-block')
@inject(EventService)
export class EventBlock {
    @bindable day = null;
    @bindable month = null;

    constructor(eventService) {
        console.log(this.day);
        console.log(this.month);
    }

    attached() {
        console.log(this.day);
        console.log(this.month);
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try this out tomorrow, seems fair enough!!